# Unable to connect to Checkpoint VPN

Tags: vpn

I am unable to establish connection with Checkpoint SNX in my UBUNTU 19.04.
Please find the snapshot attached for issue.
I am stuck at **"Starting Mobile Access Portal Agent..."**

Please let me know how to get it fixed.
Note: I am able to connect when i was using 18.04 LTS

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Please do not [post screenshots of the terminal](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/250300). Please [edit] your question to paste the text directly and apply [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code).

Comment: Nowadays it does not install so easily. see https://github.com/ruyrybeyro/chrootvpn and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/450131/vpn-ssl-network-extender-in-firefox/450132

Answer (score 2):

I happened to have the same problem while testing Check Point snx.
In my case, the problem was that Java was not installed. The following command solved it for me.

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre-headless
```